# How do you add :hover to an image on a navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

On my navigation bar instead of words that are linked to other pages it's images. I've tried to do the :hover css trick but it hasn't done anything when I try it on words it works perfectly fine. Any help would be amazing!
HTML

```css
.home {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 690px;
  margin-left: 1935px;
}

.home ul li a:link {
  color: white;
}

.home ul li a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.home ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="home">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="home.png" style="width: 650px; height:400px;">
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you added the `hover` to `a` tag?

Comment: I'm adding it to the `<img src="home.png">` which has an `a` tag attached to it just above so I'm confused what I need to add to get the `hover` to show

Comment: try with adding `hover` to `a` tag  `.home ul li a:hover {  color: black; }`

Comment: So I've just changed my code to
`.home {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 690px;
margin-left: 1935px;

}
.home ul li a:link {
color: red;
}
.home ul li a:visited {
color: red;
}
.home ul li a:hover {
color: black;
 } `   

and nothing has changed there's still no hover box around it nor any color

Comment: Realize a few things about using images: 1) they are not accessible; blind people and search engine robots will gain nothing from your images; 2) they are not affected by `color` or any of the `font` or `text` related properties; 3) they are only affected by `background` properties if they are transparent or semi-transparent; 4) changing the text shown on an image means recreating the image in its entirety; if the width or height changes, that can affect your design much more than a corresponding change in text.

Comment: I'm only creating this site just for practice it's not going to be going anywhere :) but okay that makes sense I've changed the color property to `background-color` but still nothings changed as you say it's only for transparent or semi transparent ones so is there anyway of making it react to `:hover`

Comment: You could use a CSS [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to change its appearance in some ways, and you could apply [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)s to change it in others. But at this point we've gone way beyond your original question.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure how complicated it was to do it I thought it might have just been a case of my code being wrong or something

Answer (score 0):

you can't apply `color: white;` on images, it's just for text elements

Comment: Right okay I've deleted that thanks but there's still no hover box/change of color sadly

Comment: You have to replace <img tag with an other text tag like <p> or <h1>.....; images are note affected with color or text size